# Using path helper in partials generate wrong path in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial

I have my application "http://www.example.com/test".
When I hit the url I get the index page, where I show list of profiles.

To show each profile in the lists, I have used a partial. 
Each of the profiles have link to their own show page.

To provide the link addreess I have used Rals path helper like this

```
 profile_path(:id => whatever_id)
```

The issue is the generated url is like this:-

```
 /profile/whatever_id
```

It completely skips the app name which is "test". The expected url by me is

```
 /test/profile/whatever_id
```

Can any one tell what can be the possible cause of this?

Comment: Expected by the app or by you?  Can you post your routes please.

Comment: Is profiles index page inside module or namespace in your Rails app?

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on what you means under "app name". If the app is mounted under /test with Passenger Apache/Nginx module, then Rails app will honor the server-side prefix, and will generate correct URLs automatically, only the development environment will generate urls in the root scope.

If your app is runs standalone or via proxy setup (typical setup if the frontend webserver is an Nginx server), and you want to run it under a prefixed path then you have to use the `scope` method like this:

`Rails.application.routes do
  scope(:path => '/test') do
    # the rest of your routes go here
  end
end`

See detailed info in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-scope).